# Need to figure out how to pull a name along with the timespan out of a list

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a list that pulls timespans and selects and displays the largest timespan in the list. I need to figure out a way to display the name that also matches that timespan. Not exactly sure where to start with this. would anyone be able to get me started. some of the code I've is below.

Code: You can see I create a list of timespans from item where workmodedirectiondescription = AVAIL-IN. I need AgName = AVAIL-IN also = and then to match the agent that has the max time Listoftimespans.max and display the name of the agent that has the max time. I hope this makes sense. The biggest issue I'm having is I can create a separate list of agname but then don't know how to match the times of the agent to display the name that has the largest time. I can't add agname to the list listoftimespans because agname is of type string not timespan.

```
  var listofTimeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();

      List<NewAgent> newAgentList = new List<NewAgent>();                  

     foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
     {
         NewAgent newAgents = new NewAgent();

         newAgents.AgentName = item.AgName;

         newAgents.AgentExtension = item.Extension;

         newAgents.AgentDateTimeChange = ConvertedDateTimeUpdated;

         newAgents.AuxReasons = item.AuxReasonDescription;

         newAgents.LoginIdentifier = item.LoginId;

         newAgents.AgentState = item.WorkModeDirectionDescription;

         var timeSpanSince = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;
         newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange = timeSpanSince;

         newAgentList.Add(newAgents);

         if (item.WorkModeDirectionDescription == "AVAIL-IN")
         {
             listofTimeSpans.Add(timeSpanSince);
         }
         var comparetimeandname = new tuple<string, TimeSpan>(item.Agname, listoftimespans.max());

         max = comparetimeandname.item2;
         maxname = comparetimeandname.item1.

     }
```

Update: occurs right after the above code

```
  var availInAgents = newAgentList.Where(ag => ag.AgentState == "AVAIL-IN").ToList();

  availInAgents.Sort((t1, t2)=>t1.AgentDateTimeStateChange.CompareTo(t2.AgentDateTimeStateChange));

                    var minTimeSpanAgent = availInAgents.FirstOrDefault();
                    var maxTimeSpanAgent = availInAgents.LastOrDefault();

                    var min3 = availInAgents.Take(3).ToList();
                    var max3 = availInAgents.Reverse<NewAgent>().Take(3).ToList();

NextInLine.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, min3);
```

Edit: screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVwim.png)

Comment: Make a list of name/timespan pairs. Maybe instead of saving timespans in `listofTimeSpans`, make that a list of the agents with `"AVAIL-IN"`. Find the objects in that list with the smallest and largest time spans and you've got the name right there.

Comment: Can a list of pairs contain two datatypes? TimeSpan and String?

Comment: `Tuple<String, TimeSpan>` is one option. Another is to write your own quickie class with Name and TimeSpan properties. If you're going to be maintaining the code for a long time, I'd recommend the latter option.

Comment: so i changed my list to a SortedList<TimeSpan, string>(). it allowed me to add both agname and timespan into it, i just have to access the agname that matches the highest time. i have to research tuple as i've never used it before.

Comment: So if more than one name has the same timespan, you want to throw away the duplicates?

Comment: the timespans are updated every three seconds. it is rare that multiple agents will have the same time span but yes i'd like to only display one. doesn't matter which one

Comment: I've found that it's usually better to pick a collection class that suits the design rather than to design my application around the peculiarities of whatever collection class I first stumbled on, but it's your call.

Comment: its good advice. i appreciate it

Comment: ...on the other hand, you got it working, which isn't nothing.

Comment: not exactly. but i'm a lot closer then i was before!

Comment: So i updated my question. i ended up using a tuple as you suggested because it seems like its going to work better then the sorted list because of the way it can be accessed. When i access item two which is the names how do i pull out the name that matches the time? or will the logic already be that smart?

Comment: See my answer for how to get the min/max items out of the list.

Comment: added the code in an update as requested. only minor changes from what you have.

Comment: You break on the last line of the new code update, and `max3` is *null*? I don't know how that's even possible. `Enumerable.ToList<Source>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)` doesn't do that. On an empty sequence, it returns an empty list, but there's [no case that'll cause it to return null](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx). It throws if `this source` is null.

Comment: added screenshot @EdPlunkett

Comment: Has it actually executed that line yet?

Comment: yes it has. when you add a break somewhere after it it has no affect on the outcome.

Comment: I would like to see a screenshot with the execution line on a subsequent line, and the mouse hovering over `max3` showing `null`. Never say never, but that's an extraordinary claim.

Comment: See updated answer for alternate answer. I can't believe it matters though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's say, as discussed in comments, you collect a List of tuples representing names and their timespans. By the way, I wouldn't do that in the loop; I'd do this after the loop:

```
var availInItems = 
    newAgentList
        .Where(ag => ag.WorkModeDirectionDescription == "AVAIL-IN")
        .Select(ag => 
            new Tuple<String, TimeSpan>(ag.AgentName, ag.AgentDateTimeStateChange))
        .ToList();
```

To get the min and max timespan items, just sort the list by the `TimeSpan` values of each item, and grab the first and last items. I'm using `FirstOrDefault()` and `LastOrDefault()` instead of `First()` and `Last()` because they return null on an empty list rather than throwing an exception. That way, we more gracefully handle the case where the list happens to be empty.

```
List<Tuple<String, TimeSpan>> availInItems = new List<Tuple<string, TimeSpan>>();

//  ... populate availInItems in loop ...

availInItems.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.Item2.CompareTo(t2.Item2));

var minTimeSpanTuple = availInItems.FirstOrDefault();
var maxTimeSpanTuple = availInItems.LastOrDefault();
```

Lowest three, highest three:

```
var min3 = availInItems.Take(3).ToList();
//  There's another overload of Reverse, without the type argument, which 
//  is a meber of List<T>; it reorders the list in place and returns void. 
//  You need this one.
var max3 = availInItems.Reverse<Tuple<String, TimeSpan>>().Take(3).ToList();
```

Those are OK if you have fewer than three items in the list. You'll just get whatever it has.

### However

Both pieces of information that we're putting in the tuple are in `NewAgent`. Why get a tuple involved? No need. I'd just do this:

```
var availInAgents = 
    newAgentList
        .Where(ag => ag.WorkModeDirectionDescription == "AVAIL-IN")
        .ToList();

availInAgents.Sort((t1, t2) => 
    t1.AgentDateTimeStateChange.CompareTo(t2.AgentDateTimeStateChange));

var minTimeSpanAgent = availInAgents.FirstOrDefault();
var maxTimeSpanAgent = availInAgents.LastOrDefault();

var min3 = availInAgents.Take(3).ToList();
var max3 = availInAgents.Skip(availInAgents.Count - 3).ToList();

max3.Reverse();
```

Comment: but there is no way to print the name and time separately. it just grabs the two value of both items?

Comment: @firehotguitar88 What's grabbing what? Separately? I don't understand. Show me the code.

Comment: so this actually worked great. i just had a problem understanding it until i saw it work. sorry about that. do you know if there is a way to get the second and third person also?

Comment: your amazing Ed.

Comment: @firehotguitar88 That's what sh... I mean, thank you.

Comment: So the reverse function on var max3 does not work. min3 pulls the top three people and when you break on availinagents in max3 you get all the available agents but max3 is null. assuming it has something to do with the reverse<newagent>

Comment: @firehotguitar88 Can you add the new code, just as you have it, in an update at the end of your question?

Comment: so it worked. I can't believe it either.  thanks again for your help.

Comment: So i've run into a new problem with the same code but so much has been done here and your technically correct i'm just going to post a new question and mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think LINQ can help you.

For example, if you need the agent with max TimeSpan:

```
var maxAgent = newAgentList.Max(agnet => agnet.AgentDateTimeStateChange);
Console.writeLine(maxAgent.AgentName);
```

Comment: is that supposed to be agnet or agname

Comment: your answer also does not take into account the avail-in state.